# Rails: Polymorphic Associations: How to list associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, rails-activerecord

I have a polymorphic assocation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :companiable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :as => :companiable
end

class Publisher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :as => :companiable
end
```

and now I want to list all users and show the company they belong to. Is there a more elegant solution than this (strongly hope there is)?

```
def index
    @publishers = Publisher.all
    @agencies = Agency.all
    @users = User.all
end
```

...

```
<td><% unless user.companiable_id.nil? %>
            <% if user.companiable_type == "Agency" %>
              <%= @agencies[user.companiable_id].name %>
            <% elsif user.companiable_type == "Publisher"%>
              <%= @publishers[user.companiable_id].name %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acces the company from user, since the `belongs_to` adds a method so that you can access the other object directly by doing `user.companiable`

```
def index
   @users = User.all
end
```

and in your view

```
<td><% unless user.companiable.nil? %>
       <%= user.companiable.name %>
    <% end %></td>
```